# How to translate lists of list intro dictionaries of dictionaries?

Tags: python

so i need to create some dictionaries in dictionaries in dictionaries... I really could use a help how to write it. I am trying to figure it out but i can't get a pass creating 3rd dictionary.

so i have a list of list with my data it looks like it:

```py
my_data = [['Floor_one', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', '2000'],
['Floor_one', 'Jobless', 'Cats', 'June', '3000'], 
['Floor_two', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', '2100'],
['Floor_two', 'Jobless', 'Cats', 'June', '2200'],
['Floor_three', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', '2300'],
['Floor_three', 'Working', 'Cats', 'June', '4500']]
```

And i need to create a dictionaries out of that lists of list that is gonna look like that:

```py
my_dict = {Floor: {Month: {Working:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}, Jobless:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}
```

so in my case it should be like it:

```py
my_dict = {Floor_one: 
{May: {Working:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}, Jobless:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}, 
June: {Working:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}, Jobless:{Dogs:200, Cats: 300}
{Floor_two: 
{May: {Working:{Dogs:800, Cats: 400}, Jobless:{Dogs:1000, Cats: 3300}, 
June: {Working:{Dogs:700, Cats: 500}, Jobless:{Dogs:2100, Cats: 2300}
```

Of course my list of list is much larger like 300 lines, i have much more floors and months.
My current code looks like it:

```py
def my_function(our_data) # our data is my list of lists
    for line in our_data[1:]: #ignore first line since is name of columns
            if line[0] not in nested_dict:
                nested_dict[line[0]] = 0
    return nested_dict
```

It creates my floors but i don't know how to go from here.
Could anyone help me with that please? :) I am doing it so i could find out how many i have spend on X things with specific tributes. For example i ask for (Floor_one, May, Working, Cats) and response will be 300

Comment: The data of `my_dict` and `my_data` doesn't match, also which is the resultant output, the first or the second string.

Comment: are those strings? ['Floor_one', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', 2000],

Comment: Yes, list of my lists are strings. My bad

Comment: Kumar, I think i don't understand that; my list has all the attributes Floor, W/J, Month, D/C, number. Same  attributes you can find in my dictionary, They just in different order. Since i cannot change my excel file. Is it a big problem? My output is just a my dictionary in the end.

Comment: So the inner dictionary will have keys `Cats` and `Dogs` and how would I know the other nested keys are `May` and `Working`, or `Working` or `May`? Also you have two examples of `my_dict` in your quesstion, which one is the resultant dictionary you want?

Comment: 'Cos i wrote in exactly what order they are in my list and in what order i need them in my dictionary? first my_dict is general rule how it should look and second my_dict is how it should look with example from my_data. Both of my_dict are the same in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-consider my data structure if I were you. It's pretty complicated, you should try to make it easier to work with. Maybe start with a `dict` in the first place. Anyway, this might help you:

```py
In [15]: d = [["floor_one", "working", "dogs", "may", 2000], ["floor_one", "jobless", "cats", "june", 3000], ["floor_
    ...: two", "working", "dogs", "may", 2100]]
    ...:
    ...: import collections
    ...:
    ...: new_d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    ...:
    ...: for l in d:
    ...:     inner_inner_local_d = {}
    ...:     inner_inner_local_d[l[2]] = l[4]
    ...:     inner_local_d = {}
    ...:     inner_local_d[l[1]] = inner_inner_local_d
    ...:     new_d[l[0]][l[3]] = inner_local_d
    ...:

In [16]: new_d
Out[16]:
defaultdict(dict,
            {'floor_one': {'may': {'working': {'dogs': 2000}},
              'june': {'jobless': {'cats': 3000}}},
             'floor_two': {'may': {'working': {'dogs': 2100}}}})
```

Comment: It's very close to what i need man, only problem is that i need in month: working, jobless as as 1 dictionary not 2: it should  be like 
{'floor_one': 
   {'may': 
      {'working': {'dogs': 2000, cats: 1000}, 'jobless': {'dogs': 1500, 'cats': 2500}},
   'june': {'working': {'dogs': 2000, cats: 1000}, 'jobless': {'cats': 3000}}}

Comment: Thank you anyway my man will try to fix it for my needs ;) It's just a got an excel in it format and that i cannot change for 100% so i am trying to make an easy way for myself to get a data i need.

Comment: Updated my answer to match your exact desired output.

Comment: Hey man it's very close right now, it just didn't translate the second part of Working/Jobless and Dogs/Cats. If you add all 6 cases i posted in your "d" i think you gonna see what i mean. Right now in each month there is only Working OR Jobless and in each W/J is only Dogs or Cats. There should always be both categories.

Comment: Show me a real example of an input you'd like to test. As I see it, in each month there are only dogs / cats, not both.

Comment: Sorry for this my man. Here is a link to my csv file: [link](https://github.com/Klej177/my_csv/blob/master/data_excel.csv)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to keep data as is and run queries checking presence of certain attributes.

```
my_data = [
    ['Floor_one', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', 2000],
['Floor_one', 'Jobless', 'Cats', 'June', 3000], 
['Floor_two', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', 2100],
['Floor_two', 'Jobless', 'Cats', 'June', 2200],
['Floor_three', 'Working', 'Dogs', 'May', 2300],
['Floor_three', 'Working', 'Cats', 'June', 4500]
]

def query_volumes (query, data):
    for q in query:
        data = [d for d in data if q in d]
    volumes = [d[-1] for d in data]
    return sum(volumes)

query1 = ['Floor_three', 'June', 'Working', 'Cats']
query2 = ['Cats']

query_volumes(query1, my_data)
# RETURNS 4500
query_volumes(query2, my_data)
# RETURNS 9700
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it your way and check if it works they way i need it to.